# How to initialize a Nokogiri::XML::Element

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I would like to initialize a `Nokogiri::XML::Element` object using:

```
html = '<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>'
Nokogiri::XML::Element.new(html)
```

But currently I have to do this:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html).children.last
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to create an HTML element as XML?

Comment: To test something that receives `Nokogiri::XML::Element` as input in test.

Comment: Just so you know, Nokogiri turns on very strict checking of the XML when doing that, which can cause problems because HTML usually requires the parse and generation to relax its idea of what's valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nokogiri` provides the `make` method ([`Nokogiri::make`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri#make-class_method)) as a convenience method for creating a `DocumentFragment` and the code is nearly identical to what you are doing now:

```
def make input = nil, opts = {}, &blk
  if input
    Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(input).children.first
  else
    Nokogiri(&blk)
  end
end
```

example:

```
html = '<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>'
require 'nokogiri'
Nokogiri.make(html)
#=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2afe5af3a04c name="a" attributes=
#    [#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2afe5ac33efc name="href" value="https://example.com">] 
#     children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2afe5ac32408 "Link">]>
```

Other options include

```
Nokogiri(html).first_element_child
Nokogiri.parse(html).first_element_child
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `Nokogiri.make`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment`:

```
html = '<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>'
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment html
#=> #(DocumentFragment:0x2b296b79c0c4 { name = "#document-fragment", children = [ #(Element:0x2b296919d724 { name = "a", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x2b296919d6fc { name = "href", value = "https://example.com" })], children = [ #(Text "Link")] })] })
asd.children.last
#=> #(Element:0x2b296b7cbe50 { name = "a", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x2b296b7cbe28 { name = "href", value = "https://example.com" })], children = [ #(Text "Link")] })
```